# flutter, kotlin gradle problem while using location package

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, package, location

I got the next problem after I insert the package of location, I am trying to use location in my app but the problem said my Kotlin gradle is higher I've tried to change it manually from the Gradle file in the app level but the problem has not solved it appears in the 'android' instead any help please.

The image shows the problem that happend after adding location package.

[image: problem]

Answer (score 1):

Current: `location: ^4.4.0`

I found 2 solutions but I don't like either:

==> **SOLUTION 1:**

Change the Kotlin version in the location package in the pub-cache. In this path:

```
<your flutter folder>/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/location-4.4.0/android/build.gradle
```

change this:

```
buildscript {
    // ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.20'
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.20'
    repositories {
```

**This is a bad solution.** It will let you build but you will lose the change if you clear the pub cache or if you run your code in a different computer.
Also, I'm not really sure if this badly affects the location package in some other ways that I haven't noticed yet.

==> **SOLUTION 2:**

There's a newer beta version of location package, `location: ^5.0.0-dev.8`.
It uses Kotlin 1.6.21 so your problem would be gone.

**Bad thing**: it's not backwards compatible with version `location: ^4.4.0`, and it's still in development so not recommended in production mode.

Answer (score 0):

Update **Location** plugin gradle version **1.4.20 to 1.5.20**

Comment: how? because all the time i thought it need to downgrade not upgrade, isn't the location package out of date ?

Comment: Shallow answer.  Could you please provide more info? Try to explain not only what to do, but how to do it.